# Cmake: how to delete old variables with a new build

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to configure my app with cmake, which depends on

```
cmake -DVERSION_TO_BUILD ../
```

In my CMakeList I wrote that checker

```
if (NOT VERSION_TO_BUILD)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Please, set VERSION_TO_BUILD")
endif()
```

In first configure all works normally, but in the next time when I try to reconfigre like

```
cmake ../
```

When I configure my app without -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=1, cmake throws an error (as expected).
After that, I configure an app with -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=1 and it does not give an error (as expected).
However, when I go back to the first option without -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=1 it does not give an error. I checked it by calling message and found that it exists.

I found out that cmake saved VERSION_TO_BUILD variable. So my checker doesn't work correctly.

Of course, I can't use set in CMakeList because VERSION_TO_BUILD is external dependency.
How can I fix this so that I don't delete the cmake folder?

Comment: `cmake -DVERSION_TO_BUILD ..` does not build anything; it (re)configures the project. `cmake --build .` would be used to build the project after configuration. Please add some info about how your build process looks and more info about the purpose of the `VERSION_TO_BUILD` variable. (this is likely an XY problem)

Comment: @fabian Okay, my bad. I just try to configure my app.
I have 2 options to configure. First is when I using cmake ../
Second is cmake -DVERSION_TO_BUILD ../
And after second, my first version doesn't work because cmake saved my variable. But I don't need it

Comment: what do you mean by "And after second, my first version doesn't work"? What doesn't work about it, do you get some error, or what does not work as expected? From the question, it reads as if you actually *want* to specify VERSION_TO_BUILD each time because it could be different each time? If not, then what is the problem with the fact that CMake stores it?

Comment: @codeling When I configure my app without -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=1, cmake throws an error (as expected). After that, I configure an app with -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=1 and it does not give an error (as expected). However, when I go back to the first option without -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=1 it does not give an error. I checked it by calling message and found that it exists.
So, I don't need to save it, when I configure cmake without that variable

Comment: I think I get the "problem" - so you want the error to be thrown if cmake is called without VERSION_TO_BUILD? why is it a problem if it reuses the previous value?

Comment: @codeling because for my app it should make an error after cmake ../ always :)

Comment: How about [unset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/unset.html)ting the variable at the end of the configure run?

Comment: @codeling Yes! That's it! Thanks to you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a `-D` option during the configuration of your cmake project sets a cache variable. The cache is persisted for builds and future reconfiguration. Note that cmake does not treat cache variables that were persisted and cache variables that are passed via command line any different during reconfiguration of a project.

In fact after editing the project files building the project may actually cause the version of cmake that causes a reconfiguration of the project without passing any additional information (i.e. `cmake <path to build dir>`) to be run automatically.

It would be preferrable to simply set up different build directories for both configurations, assuming there are no conflicting files written e.g. to the source tree, if you do this.

Other than that you can simply reconfigure the project explicitly deleting a cache entry using the `-U` option

```
cmake -U VERSION_TO_BUILD <path to build dir>
```

Comment: So, I can use unset too)

Comment: @Imidori You could use `unset`, but that is probably not what you want. If you're configuring the project and then edit one of the `CMakeLists.txt` files (or just `touch` it) cmake will automatically repeat the configuration without modifying the cache, but that way just building the project could change, if `VERSION_TO_BUILD` is supposed to be considered defined or not which is almost certainly unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I go back to the first option without -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=1 it does not give an error.

This is the expected behaviour, documented in the manual. `cmake ..` reconfigures the targets with exactly the same arguments that are used previously. You should explicitly change the arguments if you want update the targets.

```
cmake -DVERSION_TO_BUILD=NO ..
```

You may also remove CMakeCache.txt if you want to reset the arguments to their default values.

Comment: is there another way to solve it?

Comment: No, this is a well documented behaviour for developer convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason need that `VERSION_TO_BUILD` variable to be specified each time you configure; and want an error if it's not specified via -D..., then you can remove it at the end of the config run; use the [unset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/unset.html) command for that:

In CMakeLists.txt:

```
# ... all other CMake code
UNSET(VERSION_TO_BUILD)
```

The "real" solution would probably be to find a non-saving way of passing in the information to CMake, but I don't currently know of any way to pass a variable into CMake which is not cached. Maybe the folks at the [CMake Discourse](https://discourse.cmake.org/) could tell you one.

I do suspect, however, that the behavior you intend is currently not really something that CMake supports directly. From my experience, the mindset for CMake is that a build directory typically represents a specific build configuration; if anything about that configuration should change, a new build directory should be created.